# CSS file for children of one section

Tags: css

I have many `sections` on my page. Every of these `sections` can have similar elements, for example in each of these sections can be `h1` element.

I want to add css files where every of these css will be for only one section.

For example I have three sections on my page where ids are:

- section1 -- section2 -- section3

I have three css files too with names:

- section1.css -- section2.css -- section3.css

How to do that every css file refers to a suitable section?

Maybe can I add any additional block to every of these css files with section id?

Comment: *I want to add css files where every of these css will be for only one section.* - Wait, why? What problem are you trying to solve by having separate CSS files for every section?

Answer (score 2):

I don't know why you want to do that, but if you want to have separate styles for each section which has unique ID just use the ID as a selector. For example:

**section1.css**

```
#section1 h1{ color:red;} 
#section1 .someclass { color: blue}
```

**section2.css**

```
#section2 h1 { color: green;} 
#section2 .someclass {color:yellow;}
```

And so on. You will have separate styles for each section selecting them by ID. I think it's the easiest way

Comment: I am doing site where user will can add own sections and own styles. I hope that user have not to know id for section and write this id with every block in css editor

Comment: @user3271955 *user will can add own sections and own styles* That's a different problem than what you described in your question. You should ask a new question and specify that this is the problem you're trying to solve.

Answer (score 1):

CSS files doesn't refer to its elements (in your case `id`). Its the selector which actually targets elements. You can use separate for each of the children on each section.

Instead use inheritance with each `id`.

Have a look at the example snippet below:

```css
/* Section 1 */
#section1 {
  background: #ff0;
  padding: 10px 15px;
}

#section1 p {
  background: #99d;
}

/* Section 2 */
#section2 {
  background: #99d;
  padding: 10px 15px;
}

#section2 p {
  background: #ae9;
}

/* Section 3 */
#section3 {
  background: #ae9;
  padding: 10px 15px;
}

#section3 p {
  background: #ff0;
}

body {
  margin: 0;
}
```

```html
<div id="section1">
  <strong>Section 1</strong>
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Quas quam dicta libero qui sapiente beatae sunt, aspernatur et reprehenderit natus dolor, sint aliquid iure magni quibusdam accusantium provident perspiciatis fugit.</p>
</div>

<div id="section2">
  <strong>Section 2</strong>
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Quas quam dicta libero qui sapiente beatae sunt, aspernatur et reprehenderit natus dolor, sint aliquid iure magni quibusdam accusantium provident perspiciatis fugit.</p>
</div>

<div id="section3">
  <strong>Section 3</strong>
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Quas quam dicta libero qui sapiente beatae sunt, aspernatur et reprehenderit natus dolor, sint aliquid iure magni quibusdam accusantium provident perspiciatis fugit.</p>
</div>
```

Hope this helps!